# Display categories and their IDs

Tags: categories, hierarchical

Could anyone please tell me the code to display parent categories and their children along with their IDs?

I'd like to, for example, print them in this way:

Europe, United Kingdom, London (Europe is parent category, UK is child, London is child of UK)
102, 150, 175 (these are their relevant IDs)

Europe, France, Paris
102, 153, 189

Europe, France, Cannes
102, 153, 192

what i want to do is this: The steps I Followed (please check this link)

I only want to change this code:

```
<ul> <?php wp_list_categories('show_count=1&title_li=&hide_empty=0'); ?></ul>
```

so that the list of of all the categories and their childs will be displayed along with their ids in this format:

Example: **Europe,United Kingdom,London, East Ham : 25,28,34,36** this is just one parent category (Europe) and its childs (Uk) the child of UK is London, and the child of london is East Ham. 25 is the id of Europe, 28 is the id of UK, 34 is the id of London, 36 is the id of East Ham

Please note: I just want to display this list on a page as described in the link above. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a list of the current post's categories and parents, or just a general list of categories?  If the former, you can use [`get_category_parents()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents).  If you're in The Loop, for example:

```
<?php
    if( have_posts() ) : 
        while( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();
            // Post stuff
            // ...

            $cats = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );
            foreach( $cats as $c ) {

                $category_list = ''; // initialize our text strings
                $category_id_list = '';

                $display = false;
                $sep = ', ';
                $nice = false;
                $parents = get_category_parents( $c, $display, $sep, $nice );

                $_parents = explode( ',', $parents ); // convert the string to an array
                $_parent_ids = array(); // initialize the array for the IDs
                foreach( $_parents as $p ) {
                    $_parent_ids[] = get_cat_ID( $p );
                }
                // convert the $_parent_ids array to a string
                $parent_ids = implode( ', ', $_parent_ids );
                echo( "$parents $parent_ids" );
            }

        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

[Edited:  Cleaned up the code, and took advantage of PHP's `implode()` function]